# Unzip a single file in a tbz archive

Tags: linux, unix, zip, tar, bzip

I have the following archived directory:

```
itunes20140618.tbz
```

I want to extract single file from it called:

```
itunes20140618/video
```

How would I do this?

So far, I am doing

```
$ bzip2 -d /tmp/itunes20140618.tbz
```

But it seems to create a tar directory of everything. How would I extract just the single video file?

Comment: What's the programming question here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different versions of `tar` around, but on my machine I can do this:

```
tar xjf archive.tbz filename
```

To extract filename from archive.

If that doesn't work you can use:

```
bzip2 -dc archive.tbz | tar xvf - filename
```

Which uses `bzip2` to extract to stdout and then pipe to `tar`.

In both cases you can replace the `x` option with `t` to get a list of files.  Eg:

```
tar tjf archive.tbz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tar` command and pass the path of the desired file or folder as an argument to it:

```
tar xjf test.tbz /path/to/file/in/archive
```